# Spyder "Graphics backend" "automatic" option not working on M1 macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, spyder, apple-m1

I've installed the native version of python3 through miniforge and the intel version of Spyder through homebrew. Everything is working fine with one exception, my plots seem to work with the "graphics backend" "inline" option. When I try to select the "automatic" option, or any other option rather than inline, the IPython doesn't initiate. Has anyone had the same problem?

Kind regards,

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version? This should be fixed in our latest one (5.2.0), so please update to it if you're not using it already.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the reply. I am using:
* Spyder version: 5.1.5 None 
* Python version: 3.9.5 64-bit
* Qt version: 5.12.10
* PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
* Operating System: Darwin 21.1.0
I installed it recently through homebrew.

Comment: Ok, if you installed it through Homebrew then you can easily update to our 5.2.0 version, released two weeks ago. Please do that and let me know if this problem is fixed for you.

Comment: Carlos, it is working fine with the version 5.2.0.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to write an answer below so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is fixed in our **5.2.0** version, released in November 2021.